# Dealing with spaces in field names

Tags: mongodb

Here is what the collection looks like:

```
{
"resident_ID": "23mgomeg3gmf32a",
"membership": "Bronze",
"Former City": "SARATOGA SPRINGS",
"Current City": "WHITE PLAINS"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{
"resident_ID": "042tj03mf23ftwf",
"membership": "Gold",
"Former City": "NIAGRA FALLS",
"Current City": "NEW ROCHELLE"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{
"resident_ID": "0rd86tx60pxfv5o",
"membership": "Bronze",
"Former City": "NIAGRA FALLS",
"Current City": "NIAGRA FALLS"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{
"resident_ID": "v3g8myx7ltw4j77",
"membership": "Gold",
"Former City": "SARATOGA SPRINGS",
"Current City": "SARATOGA SPRINGS"
}
```

I want to create a query that only returns the resident_ID's of those who do not have the same Former and Current City for people with Gold membership while ignoring missing values. In SQL, this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT resident_ID, [Former City], [Current City]
FROM tbl_ReportedResidence
WHERE [Former City]=[Current City] AND membership='Gold' 
AND [Former City] IS NOT NULL
AND [Current City] IS NOT NULL;
```

The expected output would thus be:

```
resident_ID       Former City     Current City
042tj03mf23ftwf   NIAGRA FALLS    NEW ROCHELLE
```

I have tried using the following, but they would return all resident_ID's with Gold membership and non-null values while ignoring the not equal to check for the Former and Current City:

```
db.getCollection("tbl_ReportedResidence").find(
{
"membership" : "Gold",
"Current City" : {
"$ne" : null
},
"Former City" : {
"$ne" : null
},
"$where" : "'Former City' != 'Current City'"
},
{
"resident_ID" : 1.0,
"Former City" : 1.0,
"Current City" : 1.0
}
);
```

I also tried replacing

```
"$where" : "'Former City' != 'Current City'"
```

with this based on a previous question I found that seemed to ask the same thing:

```
"$expr": {"$ne": ["Former City", "Current City"]}
```

But somehow, nothing seems to work and I keep getting the same results that ignore my attempts to filter the output to only include documents that do not have the same non-null Former City and Current City!

Edit: Since it turns out my method was not incorrect, I renamed this question to highlight the underlying issue with my implementation for future folks who might encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to note: You've made things more difficult for yourself, choosing property names with spaces in them.

Now, onto the query issue: the properties in question, when using `$where`, need to be preceded by `this`. And you won't be able to use dot-notation like `this.Current City` because of the space. You'll need to use brackets (e.g. `this['Current City']`.

So your query needs to be something like:

```
db.users.find(
  {membership:"Gold",
   "Current City": { $ne: null},
   "Former City": { $ne: null},
   $where: "this['Current City'] == this['Former City']"
  })
```

Things get simpler if you rename your properties to not have spaces, since you don't need as many quotes everywhere. For example, using `currentCity` and `formerCity`:

```
db.users.find(
  {membership:"Gold",
   currentCity: { $ne: null},
   formerCity: { $ne: null},
   $where: "this.currentCity == this.formerCity"})
```

Comment: Thank you! Oh my goodness, I had a feeling the spaces would make things more complicated! Unfortunately this was built before my time into an automated system, so it's not something I had any control over. It was actually the first time I had seen spaces in names like this, so I had no idea of the syntax needed to deal with them!

Answer (score 1):

your query is almost correct, the query should be like that

```
db.getCollection("tbl_ReportedResidence").find(
    {
        "membership": "Gold",
        "Current City": {
            "$ne": null
        },
        "Former City": {
            "$ne": null
        },
        "$where": function () {
            return this['Former City'] !== this['Current City']
        }
    },
    {
        "resident_ID": 1.0,
        "Former City": 1.0,
        "Current City": 1.0
    }
)
```

or you can omit the call back function

```
db.getCollection("tbl_ReportedResidence").find(
    {
        "membership": "Gold",
        "Current City": {
            "$ne": null
        },
        "Former City": {
            "$ne": null
        },
        "$where": "this['Former City'] !== this['Current City']"
    },
    {
        "resident_ID": 1.0,
        "Former City": 1.0,
        "Current City": 1.0
    }
)
```

but as per the docs  [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), `$where` scans all the documents in the collection, then if you have ton of documents in this collection, it will not be a good practice, so for mongoDB version > 3.6, we can use `$expr` operator

```
db.getCollection("tbl_ReportedResidence").find(
    {
        "membership": "Gold",
        "Current City": {
            "$ne": null
        },
        "Former City": {
            "$ne": null
        },
        "$expr": { $ne: ["$Former City", "$Current City"] }
    },
    {
        "resident_ID": 1.0,
        "Former City": 1.0,
        "Current City": 1.0
    }
)
```

all the queries are working as expected, just pick the one you need